# Google Colaboratory Keras TensorFlow LSTM very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, google-colaboratory

I would like to perform parameter tuning for a LSTM.

My `X_train` and `Y_train` data have the shape (330, 96, 2).

With the code below, the i7-4700MQ notebook CPU takes about 7 seconds per epoch. Google Colaboratory with selected GPU on hosted runtime needs 10 seconds per epoch. 
Actually, I expected Google Colaboratory to be significantly faster.

What could be the reason for that?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np

X_train = []
X_test = []
Y_train = []
Y_test = []

with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo/X_train.txt', 'rU') as file:
    X_train = np.array(eval(file.readline())).reshape(-1, 96, 2)
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo/X_test.txt', 'rU') as file:
    X_test = np.array(eval(file.readline())).reshape(-1, 96, 2)
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo/Y_train.txt', 'rU') as file:
    Y_train = np.array(eval(file.readline())).reshape(-1, 96, 2)
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo/Y_test.txt', 'rU') as file:
    Y_test = np.array(eval(file.readline())).reshape(-1, 96, 2)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(30, input_shape=(96, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(units=2, use_bias=False))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `CuDNNLSTM()` which is an optimised form of LSTM for GPUs. Also, try using TensorFlow GPU.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thanks for your help. CuDNNLSTM has accelerated training by a factor of 3-4. What exactly do you mean by Tensorflow GPU? Is GPU acceleration not possible with Keras?

Comment: You can install tensorflow-gpu which is optimized build for GPUs.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal but I guess Google Colaboraty should have already installed Tensorflow GPU, or?

Comment: No, Google Colab has tensorflow installed and not tensorflow-gpu

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal ok thanks, but should be ok when I can run code with `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`, or?